# Gradle - Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

I am new to Spring-boot and I wanted to create application using Eclipse, Spring and Gradle. After I created "Spring Starter Project" I failed to run the application. The trace says:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-12-30 19:26:36.732 ERROR 3483 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

This is my "build.gradle" file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: Post your `pom.xml`

Comment: Please post your application.properties (or .yml)

Comment: I don't see H2 in your classpath. All I see is 3 spring boot starters.

Comment: Have you tried any of these answer ?

Comment: Yes, at the moment none worked for me. I did not try to have h2 database, I just though adding one would solve the problem. So even if I tried adding dependencies `implementation` or `compile` to gradle dependencies it didn't work.

Comment: @BlackHawk3 Can you post your `application.properties` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add implementation('com.h2database.h2') in your gradle dependencies.
By default spring boot auto configures h2 with this db url "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb"

Answer (score 0):

In my case file `application.properties` was in `src/main/resources/static`, moving it to `src/main/resources` resolved the error